# Annotate en matplotlib con gráfico barras agrupadas

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy realizando una visualización que representa el total de faltas realizadas (barra azul) y recibidas (barra naranja). Estoy intentando anotar la diferencia entre ambos valores (una tercera columna), pero al ponerla encima de cada barra únicamente se me pone sobre las barras azules. Mi intención es que la anotación siempre esté encima de la barra más alta (independientemente de cúal sea su categoría/color).

Les dejo una muestra del fichero csv:

```
,,,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Aerial Duels,Aerial Duels,Aerial Duels
Squad,# Pl,90s,CrdY,CrdR,2CrdY,Fls,Fld,Off,Crs,Int,TklW,PKwon,PKcon,OG,Recov,Won,Lost,Won%
Almería,17,2.0,7,1,0,33,19,6,14,25,19,0,0,0,116,18,11,62.1
Athletic Club,19,2.0,5,0,0,27,33,7,38,18,23,0,0,0,187,41,28,59.4
Atlético Madrid,17,2.0,3,1,0,29,25,7,33,9,28,0,0,0,143,31,34,47.7
Barcelona,18,2.0,4,1,1,26,38,5,23,15,25,0,0,0,142,31,17,64.6
Betis,16,2.0,11,0,0,28,43,5,20,17,16,1,0,0,145,21,24,46.7
```

El código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.patheffects as path_effects

data = pd.read_csv('./data/fouls.csv', header=[0, 1]).rename(columns=lambda x: '' if 'Unnamed' in x else x) # load data and replace 'Unnamed...' columns with empty spaces

# compress the data (we are analyzing fouls)
fouls = data[[('', 'Squad'), ('',   '90s'),( 'Performance',   'Fls'), ( 'Performance',   'Fld')]]
fouls.loc[:,('Performance', 'diff')] = fouls.loc[:,('Performance', 'Fls')] - fouls.loc[:,('Performance', 'Fld')] # we create column representing the difference between fouls committed and drawn
fouls.loc[:,('', '90s')] = fouls.loc[:,('', '90s')].astype('int64')
fouls = fouls.sort_values(by = [('Performance', 'diff')], ascending = False)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 2.5), dpi = 200, facecolor = "#939393")
ax = plt.subplot(111, facecolor = "#939393")

fouls_committed = fouls.loc[:,('Performance', 'Fls')]
fouls_drawn = fouls.loc[:,('Performance', 'Fld')]

ax.bar(fouls.loc[:,('', 'Squad')], fouls_committed, zorder=3, color = "#ff6961")
ax.bar(fouls.loc[:,('', 'Squad')], fouls_drawn, width = 0.25, zorder=3, color = "#77dd77")

# Remove spines
ax.spines["top"].set(visible = False)
ax.spines["right"].set(visible = False)

# Add grid and axis labels
ax.grid(True, color = "lightgrey", ls = ":")
ax.set_ylabel("Number of fouls")

for rect, label in zip(ax.patches, fouls.loc[:,('Performance', 'diff')]):
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(
        rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height + 5, label, ha="center", va="bottom"
    )
# # Adjust ticks
ax.tick_params(axis = "x", rotation = 90)
```

A continuación os dejo una muestra del resultado. Mi objetivo es que los valores que están en negativo aparezcan encima de la barra verde (en vez de encima de la azul) para que no se sobrepongan:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes agregar de dónde viene `fouls`? En tu ejemplo no está definido

Comment: Tienes preguntas que han recibido respuesta y no has aceptado, por favor lee la sección [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y procesa las preguntas que has hecho, si tienen respuestas válidas entonces acéptalas, si tienen respuestas que no solucionan tu problema entonces agrega un comentario explicando lo que hace falta.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Disculpa, ya añadí el código que falta. Simplemente es una selección de columnas.